# File.Delete() in a For Each loop does not work properly

Tags: windows, vb.net, delete-file

I try to delete every file in `filepath` with this code

```
For Each filetodelete In Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
   File.Delete(filetodelete)
Next
```

It works for `.txt` files, but if I try it on `.pdf` or `.docx` files, it only deletes like 3 of them.

However, I Could output all files found with `Directory.GetFiles` to a list box.

Comment: Please add the code with wich you filled the list box. _(And put more efford in your questions. They are written once, but read ahudred times, also later by people having the same problem.)_

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will delete all your files and folders inside the given directory:

```
 Dim di as New DirectoryInfo("path here") ''Do not include additional filter parameters here

 For each file as FileInfo in di.EnumerateFiles
    file.Delete()  '''Deletes the files
 Next
 For each Folder as DirectoryInfo in di.EnumerateDirectories
    Folder.Delete(True)   '''Deletes the folders
 Next
```

Comment: Is it possible to set `Folder` to the folder of your path and just execute `Folder.Delete(True)` once, without looping?

Comment: I didn't get that ? you mean you want to delete one folder only ?

Comment: I am not the one asking the question. I just wonder if you need to loop over the content of a folder if you can recursively delete everyting in a file with one statement.